# groupby and pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

doing the following in pyspark

```
pivotDF = data.groupBy("var2","var3").pivot("VariableName").max("Value").orderBy("RecordTime")
```

How can I do the same in pandas so can benchmark both?

Comment: It would help if you gave input and output dataframes

Comment: `data.groupby(['var2','var3','VariableName'])['Value'].max().unstack('VariableName')`?